# Add contents of an IBoutletcollection to an array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, iboutletcollection

I have two IBoutletcollections called numbers and symbols. I want to add the contents of their title in an array such that the first element of the array is from numbers and second from symbols, third from numbers, fourth from symbols and so on.
Is there a way to do it?

EDIT:

```
//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray symbols; 
//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *numbers; 

-(void)setNumbers:(NSArray *)numbers 
{ 
  _numbers=numbers; 
  for (UIButton button in self.numbers) 
  { 
     Number * number = [[Number alloc]init]; 
     [button setTitle:[number randnum] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  } 
}
```

This is the code for setting the title of the outlet collection numbers.

Comment: what kind of UI elements do you have in the ib outlet collections? `UILabel`s?

Comment: they are strings. I want to add the titles of UIButtons to an array and titles are strings.

Comment: if it's an outlet collection it must contain some sort of UI elemements, so I am guessing you have labels in there (which again of course display string...)?! are you asking for the algorithm to achieve this? can you maybe share a bit of code (especially the declaration of the outlet collections)? i am going to show you the algorithm then.

Comment: one more question: do `numbers` and `symbols` contain the same number of elements?

Comment: //@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *symbols;


//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *numbers;


 
-(void)setNumbers:(NSArray *)numbers


{
    

_numbers=numbers;
    

for (UIButton* button in self.numbers) {
        Number * number=[[Number alloc]init];
        [button setTitle:[number randnum] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
This is the code for setting the title of the outlet collection numbers.

Comment: I updated the answer, does this code work for you?

Comment: why are the declarations of outlect collections commented out btw?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, assuming your `IBOutletCollections` contain elements of class `UILabel` and have the same number of elements:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *numbers;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *symbols;

NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.numbers.count+self.symbols.count];
for (int i = 0; i < self.numbers.count+self.symbols.count; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        [result addObject:((UIButton *)self.numbers[i]).titleLabel.text];
    }
    else{
        [result addObject:((UIButton *)self.symbols[i]).titleLabel.text];
    }
}
```

The solution to your problem is to run a loop and in the loop do a modulo calculation with 2 to find out when you have an even or odd position in the result array, and then add the element from the appropriate `IBOutletCollection`. Is this clear?

Comment: `[result count]` will yield 0, as count does count the number of elements in an array. not the initial capacity.